# How does Google Maps LatLngBounds.isEmpty work?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, openlayers

I don't quite understand how **Google Maps**'s `google.maps.LatLngBounds.isEmpty` function works. What defines a `LatLngBounds` as being empty or not? Does `LatLngBounds` somehow have a record of all vectors and points on a map and check to see if any reside within the bounding box?

I am curious about this because I am working on an interface between **OpenLayers** and **Google Maps**, and there is no `isEmpty` method for `OpenLayers.Bounds` objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Appears to check if the bounds actually represents a valid bounds (contains at least a SW and a NE Point)

http://jsfiddle.net/k5zH9/1/